# I am trying to convert String to array then to integer using android studio app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to convert a string to an array, then to an integer by summing values based on the letters in the array. The problem is every time I make the Android app, the app cannot read the last value of array. The same code is working fine in Eclipse.

For example, if you put `"abc"`, you will get 3, but it should be 6.

```
 public void start(View v) {
     int sum = 0
     EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
     TextView result  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

     String y = name.getText().toString();
     String[] array = y.split("");
     int[] x = new int[y.length()];

     for (int i = 0; i < y.length(); i++) {
         String letter = array[i];
         if (letter.equals("a")) {
             x[i] = 1;
         }
         if (letter.equals("b")) {
             x[i] = 2;
         }
         if (letter.equals("c")) {
             x[i] = 3;
         }

         sum = sum + x[i];
     }

     result.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
}
```

Layout:

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="start" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

}
```

Comment: Your loop seems to be ok. Can you look at y.length result with a log ? Maybe the split didn't work correctly with "" ? Also try with "a b c" and split(" ") if the length actually equals 2 or the split is not right. Put a log on sum too in your loop and show us the result :)

Comment: try array.length() instead of y.length()

Comment: I have tried  array.length didnt work same results

Comment: I tried also to input "a" then show the result from first if but it shows  0

Comment: if i put space after the input it will work fine but it is not what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to stick to a `String` array, to properly split your `String` to characters, instead of the following:

```
String[] array = y.split("");
```

You should do something like this:

```
String[] array = y.split("(?!^)");
```

Splitting with `""` as the regex will result in an empty string in your array at index 0.

Another option is to use a `char` array instead:

```
int sum = 0

EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
TextView result  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

String y = name.getText().toString();

char[] array = y.toCharArray();
int[] x = new int[y.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < y.length(); i++) {
    char letter = array[i];
    if (letter == 'a') {
        x[i] = 1;
    }
    if (letter == 'b') {
        x[i] = 2;
    }
    if (letter == 'c') {
        x[i] = 3;
    }

    sum = sum + x[i];
}

result.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution to the above problem

```
int charTotal =0;
String input=editText.getText.toString().trim();
final static String alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++){
 charTotal = charTotal + alphabet.indexOf(input.charAt(i))+1;}
result.setText(String.valueOf(charTotal))
```